# Is Zumba Fitness 2 (Wii) an accurate representation of Zumba?

Tags: zumba, video-games

I just got Zumba Fitness 2 for the Nintendo Wii, and prior to receiving it I knew almost nothing about Zumba. I understand Zumba is a fitness routine based on Latin dance, but when playing the game I'm surprised at how simple some of the steps/routine are.

The game appears to have only 4 different "steps" for each dance style, and maybe 5-7 different dance styles. Most of the steps seem pretty uncomplicated. Things like taking one step back and then one step forward. Or facing left and then facing forward.

I understand the main point of Zumba is fitness and not dance, but I honestly expected something more complicated. So I'm wondering, are the simple steps in this game really all there is to Zumba routines? Or is this a sort of "dumbed down" version? In short, **how accurate is the depiction of Zumba in *Zumba Fitness 2*?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(I quizzed my resident Zumba expert, who has much experience with the class and has also played the game)

The class depends heavily on the instructor - if you have a low-key instructor, it'll be a low key class.  However, the game's instructor is probably at the low end of the impact scale.

Each of the moves in a real Zumba class has different "difficulty" levels, and you can scale the move depending on how much experience you have with it, and how hard you want to work out.  The game doesn't seem to have this level of variety.

The game gives limited instruction about each move, and this is similar to the way the class works.  Most instructors will just demonstrate and expect you to follow along as best you can.  There might be some "tutorial" time if it's the first time the move has ever been done for the class.

As far as dance styles and steps, the class is far more broad and open-ended.  A class may consist of 8 songs with 20 moves each, and these songs may change from class to class or from instructor to instructor.  The variety in the game is not at all representative.

Answer (score 1):

I think Zumba 2 has a lot of variety and compared to Zumba 1 it actually works you hard, but then again, only you can effectively work yourself hard. The more energy you use, the harder you work yourself, the longer you do it. Its about commitment and effort. I couldn't say about actual Zumba classes as I've never been, but I really like the wii games. I get really into them, it works up a sweat and Zumba 2 has left me with some pains that Zumba 1 hadn't (as in working different areas harder)